# How to exact match filter on change of select on react-table?

Tags: react-table

I'm trying to achieve an exact match if there is a selected filter on select. Now it's working like include it is working like this: If I select "dark chocolate" on select, it shows only "dark chocolate" rows which is completely perfect. But if I select "chocolate", it shows both "chocolate" and "dark chocolate", like using includes().

It's filtered correctly when using like:
`{ id: 'your_column_id', accessor: 'your_accessor', filter: 'equals' }`

But problem is, I don't want to filter the table on initilazing, I want to filter for the selected value on select and if there is no selected value, it should show all. But if I use like that, I can't see any row until I select a value from select. My selection code is:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (selectedType) {
      setFilter("type", selectedType.type)
    } else {
      setFilter("type", false)
    }
  }, [selectedType])
```

Probably I should set also 'equals' if `selectedType`, and unset for else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I handled with adding a custom filter:

```
function exactMatchFilter(rows, id, filterValue) {
    return rows.filter(row => {
      const rowValue = row.values[id]
      return (rowValue === filterValue || !filterValue)
    })
  }
```

.

```
  {
    Header: "something",
    accessor: 'something',
    filter: exactMatchFilter,
  }
```